# Javascript; unset a function?

Tags: javascript, function, unset

I'm pretty new to javascript. I have this function and I'd like to unset it when the screen size is less than 1024. I have two functions: a document ready function and a window resize function. When resizing the screen below 1024 I'd like the function to be unset. How to manage this?

Here is my code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if(width > 1024) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 80; // add 80 for margin + padding
        var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();

        if(rcol_height > lcol_height) $("#leftCol2").css('height',(rcol_height - 80) + 'px');
        else $("#rightCol2").css('height',lcol_height + 'px');
    }, 500);
    }
});


$(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if(width < 1024) {
//I'd like the margin function to be unset.
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){
        var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 80; // add 80 for margin + padding
        var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();

        if(rcol_height > lcol_height) $("#leftCol2").css('height',(rcol_height - 80) + 'px');
        else $("#rightCol2").css('height',lcol_height + 'px');
    }, 500);
    }

});
</script>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: why "unset" the function ? if you want to re-enable it again you'll need to add a listener to know the actual width (on the resize event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to unset it, since you might be needing it again in case the window size increases beyond 1024px. Here is a slightly optimized version of your code:

```
function handleMargins() {
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if (width > 1024) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height(); // use original margin
            var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();

            if (rcol_height > lcol_height) $("#leftCol2").css('height', (rcol_height - 80) + 'px');
            else $("#rightCol2").css('height', lcol_height + 'px');
        }, 500);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 80; // add 80 for margin + padding
            var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();

            if (rcol_height > lcol_height) $("#leftCol2").css('height', (rcol_height - 80) + 'px');
            else $("#rightCol2").css('height', lcol_height + 'px');
        }, 500);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(handleMargins);

$(window).resize(handleMargins);
```

Apart from being more readable, now the same code executes when you first open the page **AND** on resize (imagine what would happen in your original code if the window is initially smaller than 1024px).

---

UPDATE

See if this makes more sense (note, the boundary is set to 400px, so you need to shring that jsfiddle box to about twice the size of the divs): http://jsfiddle.net/wdey6ngf/

I've simplified your logic and everything, just wanted to show you how it works.

---

NOTE

Depending on how complicated your end logic is going to be, this is something you can accomplish using no JS, just plain CSS with media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/rags7zg2/ It will perform much better than the JS version.

Comment: what is the difference between the two setTimeout blocs ?

Comment: Thank you. I guess you hade a `}` too many correct? I tried your code. The document ready function is working but the resize function is not. I guess that is logical since nothing happens in this function when resizing the screen below 10424 correct? How to make the margin go away after resizing below 1024?

Comment: @RobbertT Yes, fixed that brace. In the first if-block, you set what will happen in case of a bigger window - currently, I'm just using the original margins, but you should probably tweak it to your own liking using the approach I gave you.

Comment: @RobbertT I just wrote you a simpler example, show how it works both ways.

Comment: @Shomz; thank you. I do 'understand' what is happening, but when i apply this, the height of the rightCol2 div does not apply to the height of the leftCol2 and/or the other way around. It just has a fixed height. That is not feasible because the heights of the divs differ each time and per site. Also, i actually do like (i guess:)) to unset the function then resizing below 1024 because when i use js when the screen is below 1024 the divs do not stretch with the content (thats becoming longer because of the resizing). See here:http://goo.gl/UA7WQ6. When i use no js the divs do stretch. Pls help

Comment: You can modify the JS example any way you want. I just simplified it to show you it triggers on both events. Why don't you try to make it as close as what you want, and then tell me what's wrong? Start with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/wdey6ngf/

Comment: @Shomz thanks, i appreciate your help and time very much! I guess it might be wise to show more of my code.. Anyway i tried to clean it out as much as possible. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/phz1ndta/ and here: http://goo.gl/wvNf0X. You can see what happens when resizing and that the background color is not full to the bottom. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Oh, so *that* is the problem. The fix is super simple with media queries - just remove height definitions from both columns in both size versions, and that's it. See how it looks when I remove the JS code: http://jsfiddle.net/phz1ndta/1/ Is that what you were trying to achieve? I'm not sure I understand the problem anymore (and I think it's definitely not about unsetting functions). Try not to define heights, let the elements flow and use margins and padding combined with media queries to control them.

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried floating but then the height of the rightCol2 is not adjusting to the leftCol2 (in this case). I tried display: table stuff;).That seemed to be working but i have this weird problem when i use js to flip around the divs(i need to do it with js i guess because `css order:1` is not supported by all browsers. At least not at my iphone4) when resizing.See it here: http://goo.gl/fU5R8j. When opening this in IE with a screen size less than 1024 and then make it more wide the sidebar stays on the right side. This only happens when i use adsense.Any idea on this issue?:)thanks a lot

Comment: Interesting, I don't have IE here on Linux to test it with. Could be related to the table stuff. What happens if you set the width of the main column to 70%?

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll open a new topic i guess with this specific problem.. thank you for all yr help!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a global function, you can redefine it like this:

```
window.myFunction = function() {
  return false;
}
```

But you can't do it with anonymous functions obviously. So, first extract your functions:

```
function myResizer()
{
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if(width > 1024) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 80; // add 80 for margin + padding
        var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();
        if(rcol_height > lcol_height) $("#leftCol2").css('height',(rcol_height - 80) + 'px');
        else $("#rightCol2").css('height',lcol_height + 'px');
    }, 500);
    }
}
```

And then use this function to set it as a `ready` function initially:

```
jQuery(document).ready(myResizer)
```

Later on, when you need to lose that functionality, just override it with nothing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { return false; }
```

Comment: Well, can't he avoid them? :D

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. This is not working. I am sorry; javascript is really new to me. I tried:  `if(width < 1024) {
window.myFunction = function() {
  return false;
}` which didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I didn't mean you should use the **actual** name *myFunction*, that was just an example :D :D

Comment: @user2393256: bah, I don't care much about JS, so I'm used to do things some other ways.

Comment: Of course this is not working. You just created another anonymous function which does nothing instead of "undoing" your function. Why don't you just design your first function in a way that it only triggers when it should instead of trying to reverse it by tinkering around? @Lawrence me neither, and that's one of the reasons i try to avoid JS where ever i can. But i am afraid i can't do that forever

Comment: Thank you. I tried it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pag63pmz/ the document ready function is working but the resizing function is not.. How to call the function when resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Store all your code in an function, use storing settimeout in a variable, and call that in ready and onresize. Then you can use clear interval if (width < 1024).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. I'd like to understand what you are saying but sorry im not totally:) JS is really new to me. This code was some default code that was present in my theme file. Anyway, how can store it into a function. Also, how to use a clear interval? Thank you so much!